ValueError: Unexpected response type: <class 'PipelineResult'> when using Neo4j Graphrag SimpleKGPipeline
I'm building a pipeline to extract a knowledge graph from Program source files using neo4j-graphrag. While executing the pipeline, I'm encountering the following error:
ERROR - Error during pipeline execution: Unexpected response type: <class 'neo4j_graphrag.experimental.pipeline.pipeline.PipelineResult'>

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path_to_script.py", line 189, in define_and_run_pipeline
raise ValueError(f"Unexpected response type: {type(response)}")
ValueError: Unexpected response type: <class 'neo4j_graphrag.experimental.pipeline.pipeline.PipelineResult'>
Relevant Code
Here is the relevant portion of my code:
async def define_and_run_pipeline(neo4j_driver, llm, text):
try:
    kg_builder = SimpleKGPipeline(
        llm=llm,
        driver=neo4j_driver,
        embedder=SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(),
        entities=["File", "Variable", "Paragraph", "Section"],
        relations=["CONTAINS", "USED_IN", "CALLS"],
        potential_schema=[
            ("File", "CONTAINS", "Section"),
            ("Section", "CONTAINS", "Paragraph"),
            ("Paragraph", "CONTAINS", "Variable"),
            ("File", "CALLS", "Paragraph"),
        ],
        from_pdf=False,
    )
    response = await kg_builder.run_async(text=text)

    if isinstance(response, list):
        processed_response = " ".join([item.text for item in response if hasattr(item, "text")])
    elif isinstance(response, str):
        processed_response = response
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Unexpected response type: {type(response)}")

    return processed_response

except Exception as e:
    logger.error(f"Error during pipeline execution: {e}")
    raise

What I Tried
Debugging the response: I checked the type of response returned by kg_builder.run_async() and confirmed it's of type PipelineResult.
Documentation: I reviewed the neo4j-graphrag documentation but couldn't find details on how to handle PipelineResult.
Question
How should I handle the PipelineResult object returned by SimpleKGPipeline.run_async()?
Is there a standard way to process or convert PipelineResult into a format that I can work with (e.g., a string or dictionary)?
Desired Outcome
I want to process the PipelineResult object and extract the enriched knowledge graph data so it can be stored in Neo4j or further analyzed.
